# Simple C doc generator

Tags: c, documentation-generator, parser

I would like to use (find) a very simple C src code doc generator (parser). The simpler, the better.

I have looked at `Doxygen` (also `cldoc`, `codedoc`, `cweb`, `Natural Docs`) and found them too complicated and they require special tags that are distracting.

Basically I would like to parse all comments before a function call and the functions definition. Ideally it would provide a file name and line number. Perhaps something close to header file format (with comments). We all know that using a header file will not work because many programs either lack header files or not all procedures are defined as a header.

If necessary I could write something pretty quick but I would prefer to support someone else's effort if it already exists.

example:

```
    file: data.c  Line: 225
    /********************************************
     *  This procedure takes user
     *  input and does something
     ********************************************/
    *char input (
      *int destination,
      *int source,
      struct dbText strdata,
      char dbtype
    )
```

etc...